# Are rods/cones rejuvenated periodically?

Tags: eyes

Pretty much what the title states.

Some cells/structures in the human body undergo rejuvenation periodically by flushing away older cells and growth of new ones.
E.g Skin, Blood

Does this (for want of a better word) 'rejuvenation' apply to Rods/Cones within the eye too? If so, how are the old cells flushed out - or do the old cells become part of the local humour?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer can be found in the excellent lecture from 1983 [*The Life History of Retinal Cells*](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1312450/) which also has gorgeous microscope fotos. The renewal time of rod outer membrane proteins is less than two weeks. Cells stay indefinitely, as I understand, but are periodically rebuilt in a logistical nightmare/wonder.